# Why there is no access modifier named "Visible"?

Tags: access-modifiers

In OO languages like C++, Java or C#, there are access modifiers like `public`, `private`, `protected`. Some languages have other modifiers like `internal`. All of them specifies who can access a certain variable or method. And for variables, this term *access* means both the ability to read and modify. But the most common scenario for accessing variable is making it publicly visible to others but keeping the ability to modify within the class. And this is achieved through many tactics using getter setter etc.

My question is, why don't we have a access modifier for the most common scenario, which can be named something like `visible`? Then the variable marked with it can be read by external classes or methods. But can only be modified within the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion would encourage the *implementation detail* of how the state is represented within the class to be made public.

Using one level of indirection - properties - allows you to separate out the public API of a type from its implementation. That can be of great benefit:

- You can make *when* a value is computed, e.g. lazily populating some data
- You can change how a value is stored, e.g. via delegation to some other type
- You can rename the implementation details without worrying about breaking callers

I'm all for languages making it easier to expose read-only state (as C# 6 is doing with read-only automatically implemented properties, for example) but I wouldn't encourage the fields themselves to become more visible.

Comment: I think properties will be always there to serve their purposes. Specially how C# is depending on using properties now. `visible` is not going to replace them. It is just another option. How about `visible` properties?

Comment: @Gulshan: It's an option which encourages the wrong thing though, IMO. If we can make read-only properties easy to implement, why would we make fields easier to expose? Note that changing a field to a property later is a breaking change. As for `visible` properties - that's what `public string Foo { get; private set; }` does.

Comment: Thanks. I get the reasoning for C#. How about other languages like C++ or Java?

Comment: @Gulshan: Same reasoning for Java. Wouldn't like to comment on C++.